# Using grep for getting data in the Set-Cookie header in bash

Tags: bash

I have a string like this

> scnt: AAAA+jMzRkQ2NjZGMTU5OTQ4NjcxQTA4OUE0MDk2RUYwRkQwMkU0OERFQjcxRkNFQUE5QzgxRUNFMkY5NzI3QjBFMjNGNTk1MTMyNjg3NDIyMkFBQzVFREJDNzdBNkI4RDNGNzVDMzVCMjIzMDNDNjhBODgzODhDOTFFNzIyNDkzMEY1RjZEQTQ0Mjc3NDYyQzJCNjI3Qjc3RTQ1Mjc2QTU2NzdCNEVCQTAwNTdFQ0Q0ODcxMDkyRUQ4OTJDNUJBNEYyNjk4NTE5NUQxMzlFQjFCMEFFRjZGODM2ODUxQkU2MEY3RDkzQTFGQUY5N0ZCRjg2NXwxAAABYG1QuD47akz0XdTR/c2RN1Q+RHpX2shK2V9u476rlbhG/c8f72E/Z5TaFIDuA Set-Cookie: aidsp=33FD666F159948671A089A4096EF0FD02E48DEB71FCEAA9C81ECE2F9727B0E23F5951326874222AAC5EDBC77A6B8D3F75C35B22303C68A88388C91E7224930F5F6DA44277462C2B627B77E45276A5677B4EBA0057ECD4871092ED892C5BA4F26985195D139EB1B0AEF6F836851BE6;

I want to take just the string beetween

> Set-Cookie: aidsp=**thisstring**;

I have tried it with this command

```
sessionID="$(echo "$resp" | awk -F[=";"] '{print $2}')"
```

but that does not work.

Comment: Your Awk command would probably work with a bit of massaging. The sample data you posted looks like the value you want isn't in `$2` at all but it's not clear if it's correctly formatted.

Comment: `-F[=";"]` without quoting will do the wrong thing if you have a file in the current directory named `-F=` or `-F;`. This is an unlikely corner case, but exactly the sort of situation which is near impossible to debug until you understand what's going on. You want to put the argument in single quotes to avoid the shell playing any shenanigans like this with you. `-F '[=;]'` (without double quotes around the semicolon, because presumably you put them there to prevent the shell from interpreting the semicolon) will prevent the shell from doing any glob expansion on the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep` and positive lookbehind:

```
sessionID="$(echo "$resp" | grep -oP '(?<=Set-Cookie: aidsp=)[0-9A-F]*')"
```

Comment: but it's return
Set-Cookie: aidsp=1BDD357C232ABA2F2F52EB89D1924E969EC7D2D684B1BE21CA98ABEC5B7D9790F6A3B22756B35A214C4AF396570111404B00C9F072BEFD58236A884D3DE49B979F6CBDBE9E628A426276DFC4438FE792381A82E5BBC60C4FA0AF9160434D49B47760F4FA72A66011FA1FF86EACC1BAC0F5E11311FA8593FC; Domain=appleid.apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Comment: fyi, i run the curl to apple and then i want grep the header in aidsp, that header is in the set-cookie

Comment: @AlchaD. Copy my command and try again. I changed a little bit.